# Lighbox instead of enlarge on click in Typo3 9?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

Is there any way that I can get the "enlarge on click" to work as a Lightbox in TYPO3 9?

Answer (score 1):

There were some extensions (e.g. perfectlightbox), but I have no experience with them in v9. Maybe someone can recommend one in another answer.

But basically it is easy to do it in your sitepackage:

First you include your preferred lightbox's .css and .js.

For fluid_styled_content (all the default content elements) these constants enable the HTML attributes on media-links:

[image: Constant Editor]